# react: override button color from premade component

Tags: reactjs

I am importing a library from which I take the button:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
  <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => props.chatIDState(chatRoom.chatIDFromTableChats)}>open</Button>
```

This button is rendered blue, but I want to change the color. I tried creating a css class and I tried setting the color directly, neither worked.

How can I override the default color and give it top render priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you can have classnames

Css

```css
.Button {
  color: black;
}

/* Increase the specificity */
.Button:disabled {
  color: white;
}
```

React

```js
<Button disabled className="Button">Click me</Button>
```

**Update**

Inline styling

```js
 <Button variant='contained' sx={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>HELLO</Button>
```

You can also add `!important` **(which is NOT encouraged)** in your css which will override the native styles.

```css
.Button {
  background: red !important;
}
```

React

```js
<Button className="Button">Click me</Button>
```

Reference:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

Comment: I did this multiple times by now, and the color is not changed.

Comment: @innom I've updated my answer with some extra info

Comment: thank you, this clearified things for me!

Comment: If you want override the default color, you should look at this [example in the documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#customization). You will get a reusable component.